# Processing a generic list of implementations in a specific way

Tags: java, design-patterns

Suppose I had a marker interface like so:

```
public interface Widget { };
```

and various implementations of that interface:

```
public class AWidget implements Widget {
    ....
    public String getSomeAttribute() { return ...; }
}

public class AnotherWidget implements Widget {
    ....
    public String getAnotherAttribute() { return ...; }
}
```

Further suppose I had some code that creates a `List` and tries to process them:

```
List<? extends Widget> widgets = someMethodToCreateWidgets();
```

Is something like the following possible where in one class I loop through and process the widgets

```
for(Widget widget : widgets) {
    anotherClass.process(widget);
}
```

and `anotherClass` has method signatures like the following?

```
public class AnotherClass {
    public void process(AWidget widget) {
        ....
        widget.getSomeAttribute();
        ....
    }

    public void process(AnotherWidget widget) {
        ....
        widget.getAnotherAttribute();
        ....
    }
}
```

I feel like I've seen an implementation similar to this before in concept but I'm struggling with getting something like it working. Ultimately I'm trying to avoid a one `process()` method that has to have a bunch of

```
if ( widget instanceof AWidget ) {
    ... 
} 
else if ( widget instanceof AnotherWidget ) { 
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Will the process method do unique processing things for each unique kind of Attribute?

Comment: Yes each `widget` would have different processing required and their own unique attributes. I know one option would be to potentially take a Command Pattern approach but my goal was to keep the processing independent of the widgets themselves.

Comment: Well you could add a process method to Widget, or you could have Widget return a list of Attributes, which have their own process method (Attribute could be an enum with a unique implementation of process for each enum element, that way you could share attribute code from one Widget subclass to another, I guess that would depend on if a unique processing is based on the attribute or attribute plus widget subtype).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for something that's called "double dispatch". The Visitor pattern is one common way of handling this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: Thanks! The term "double dispatch" was what I was looking for but couldn't remember.